# Issue in accesing a website hosting on weblogic server through IIS

Tags: iis, weblogic12c, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

We are facing issue while configuring IIS setup for weblogic servers.
Following are the environment details:

IIS8.5 on windows 2012 R2 standard 64x, wls_plugin_12.2.1.2.0 for weblogic server.

We have done the following steps:

1. Created a new web site on IIS.
2. Enabling the authentication settings.
3. Enabling the Directory browsing.
4. Added the script mapping in Handler mapping and set the path of iisproxy.dll as executor.
5. ISAPI filter setting for the iisproxy.dll

We are able to view the directory structure while accessing the IP and Port, but the request is not redirecting to the weblogic ip and port what we have configured in iisproxy.ini.

Is there any web.config or handler settings required to process the request?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that we are using wls-Plugin12.2.1.2.0 whose iisproxy.dll is not working in IIS8.5 on windows 2012 R2 server. After using the lower version of the plugin, able to access the web logic instance through proxy the IIS.

After that we are able to view the login page of web logic instance but not able to login to the application as it through s "404 Not found error". For this we have to change the handler mapping settings --> Request restrictions --> Mapping --> uncheck the invoke handle, restart the iis application and try browsing again. You will be able to login to web logic applications.